# Microsoft Unity HierarchicalLifetimeManager Deadlock

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a self hosted async c# webapi that is using OWIN and Unity 5.5.0.

I encountered an issue during some stress testing where after several hours the webapi would stop processing requests and the client calls would timeout.

I generated a crash dump using adplus in hang mode, opened the dump  in visual studio and found that my application was getting locked on the unity method SynchronizedLifetimeManager.GetValue()

[Threads Blocked by SynchronizedLifetimeManager.GetValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wGP.png)

the code from that method should be

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve a value from the backing store associated with this Lifetime policy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the object desired, or null if no such object is currently stored.</returns>
    /// <remarks>Calls to this method acquire a lock which is released only if a non-null value
    /// has been set for the lifetime manager.</remarks>
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
        object result = SynchronizedGetValue();
        if (result != null)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My understanding of the method is a request comes in to retrieve the object, if the object has not been set it returns but leaves the lock. When the object gets set the lock the monitor is exited and threads should be able to call.

My visible problem is that at some point unity does not have a value for that lifetime manager and blocks the threads, but set is not called to release them.

Option 1: at some point the value in the lifetime manager was changed to null. What would cause this to happen?
Option 2: The SetValue call to release the lock is failing or not being made at all. What causes the value to get set?

My assumption is that somewhere in my code an exception is not properly handled and is causing this issue, but I am not sure where to start looking and was hoping for a better understanding of what unity is trying to do.

The application has a class where we register interfaces to types for IOC. This is used for most mappings. However, it is a workflow application so at one point in all calls we look up what workflow class to call and tell unity to resolve the type string and inject any objects needed.

Comment: We tried adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to all async calls in the application but it locked up again.